# Как получить путь к файлу, который вызывает данную функцию

Tags: c++, windows, c++17

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог получить путь к файлу который вызывает функцию и эта функция могла работать с данным путем (желательно это сделать максимально автоматизированным, то есть чтобы не надо было вводить что-либо в аргументы функции)

Например: есть стандартный файл main.cpp и файлы test.h и test.cpp(например)

test.h:

```
#pragma once

class Test{
public:
    static void getPath();
};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

void Test::getPath(){
    // Как-то получить путь к файлу, в данном случае путь к main.cpp (так как вызывает эту функцию он)

    // Какие-то действия с этим путем
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

int main(){
   Test::getPath();

   return 0;
}
```

Извиняюсь за возможные ошибки в коде (я набирал его на телефоне и здесь)

C++17, компилятор я не помню, но IDE - Visual Studio 22

Comment: Еще раз... Файл вызывает функцию (это как?), путь которого надо получить? Вы бы не могли сформулировать свой вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что вы хотите?

Comment: Добавил пример, надеюсь поможет

Comment: Никакого `main.cpp` при выполнении программы нет. Много у вас на компьютере .cpp-файлов от браузера, например?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C++20:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

int sum(int x, int y, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << loc.file_name() << '\n';
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    sum(1, 2);
}
```

С помощью нестандартной функции `__builtin_FILE()`, которая, тем не менее, работает на всех основных компиляторах: Clang, GCC, MSVC.

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int x, int y, const char *filename = __builtin_FILE())
{
    std::cout << filename << '\n';
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    sum(1, 2);
}
```

По-стариковски, через макрос. Такое работает даже в С.

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(const char *filename, int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << filename << '\n';
    return x + y;
}

#define SUM(...) sum(__FILE__, __VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    SUM(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: А смысл? :) Я все подводил ТС к тому, что он, похоже, неверно вопрос задает, и что ему нужен путь к исполняемому файлу...

Comment: @Harry Мне по вопросу вообще непонятно, зачем ему путь. Может и для правильных целей, типа для логирования.

Comment: Тогда зачем именно путь, а не просто имя файла? Путь ведь существует только в момент компиляции...

Comment: @Harry Для меня это синонимы. :) Посмотрим что ТС скажет.

Comment: Мне нужен путь для логов

Comment: @Harry Вот и ответ.

Comment: @LGL Тогда можно еще добавить номер строки и имя функции (аналогично).

Comment: Просто имя не подойдёт, так как у меня уже довольно большой проект и в нем много файлов и папок

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @LGL В смысле вариант из ответа дает вам только имя без пути? Если да, в студии это исправляется флагом `/FC`.

Comment: Я отвечал @Harry ("Тогда зачем именно путь, а не просто имя файла? ") :)

Comment: Тогда `__FILE__` — с головой...

Comment: Проблема лишь в том, что и `__FILE__` и   `__builtin_FILE ()` возвращают только имя файла (без пути к нему (как я понял ТС хочет путь, хотя бы от корня проекта))

Comment: @avp На каком компиляторе? В студии это чинится флагом `/FC`. В остальных компиляторах, я предполагаю, что они возвращают точно тот путь, который был указан во флагах компилятора.

Comment: gcc/g++. Может там и есть флаг, модифицирующий __FILE__ (я не знаю)

Comment: @avp Не, еще раз, они возвращают путь ровно как он был передан компилятору. Если написать `g++ a/b/1.cpp`, получите `"a/b/1.cpp"`.